# Angular and Spring Boot - Saving a Excel File / Error "Response is not a Blob" at second time

Tags: angular, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, blob

I have the following Problem: I am trying to download an Excel-File (.xlsx) from a REST-API.

Short Description of the app: There are Projects, which can be downloaded as an Excel file with all their data.

Everything works the first time I download the file. But if I try to download the file a second time, the error "Response is not a blob" occours. I am using Angular 11 and Spring Boot with the Apache POI.

I set some Breakpoints and noticed, that the Breakpoint in my Backend-Controller dosent get triggered the second time, so I assume, its a Frontend bug (also no error in the Spring-Console)

Here is my code:

```
// Component (the selected projects ids are emitted to the service)
      exportProjects() {
       const exportIds = this.selection.selected.map(x => x.id);
       this.projectService.downloadSelectedProjects(exportIds);
      }
```

```
// Service
  downloadSelectedProjects(selectedProjectIds) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('selectedProjectIds', selectedProjectIds);
    return this.http.get(this.PROJECT_API_URL + Config.services.projects.exportSelectedProjectListExcel, {
      params: params,
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
      .subscribe(res => {
        let binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(res);
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: 'application/octet-stream'}));
        const filename = "test.xlsx";
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
    });
  }
```

```
// Backend-Controller
    @GetMapping(value = "/exportSelectedProjectListExcel")
    @ResponseBody
    public void exportSelectedProjectListExcel(@RequestParam("selectedProjectIds") List<Long> selectedProjectIds,
                                               HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try (SXSSFWorkbook xlsx = projectService.getSelectedProjectListExcel(selectedProjectIds)) {
            xlsx.write(response.getOutputStream());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To consume excel data as blob in angular service , Your response type should be byteArray `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`  or

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/exportSelectedProjectListExcel")
        @ResponseEntity<OutputStream> exportSelectedProjectListExcel(@RequestParam("selectedProjectIds") List<Long> selectedProjectIds,
                                                   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    
            try {
    SXSSFWorkbook xlsx = projectService.getSelectedProjectListExcel(selectedProjectIds)
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=File.xlsx");

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

xlsx.write(response.getOutputStream());

ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=File.xlsx")
            .contentType(new MediaType("application", "octet-stream"))
            .body(outputStream);
      }catch(Exception ex){

        }
```